# Google maps error when trying to get my API Key for android

Tags: android, api, google-maps, windows-7, keystore

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\hp\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

thats what i type into my command, on windows 7 and i keep getting the reply "keytool is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." 
=S not sure weather to install andriod again or if ive miss typed something

Comment: yes i am also having same problem but my os is windows xp

Answer (score 0):

The `keytool` utility is not part of the Android SDK, but the Java JDK.

It appears you may not have your JDK `bin/` directory in your `PATH`.  While in a command-prompt, try browsing to the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk#\bin` (# is your jdk version installed) then running the command.

Note: If you are using jdk 1.7.0 you may need to add the `-v` option to keytool as it doesn't give MD5 by default, only SHA.