# How to get google map apikey in android

Tags: android, api-key

Hi At that time working on google map. I want to display map in my activity.  I successfully display the map view.  But i cant show the map i think i have wrong api key so how can i get api key of google map. I create the keystore and all procedure but i didn't have idea how to get api key from this keystore.

I also give the all permission in manifest file and also add the google map library than also i cant show the map.in activity also extends mapactivity and also write code fro map in xml.

If anyone knows about that please tell me.

Comment: You get the apikey from google for google maps!

Comment: Which map api version are you using?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtaining_an_api_key

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Maps API Key :Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678472/get-maps-api-key-android)

Comment: just check out my post in this link : you will find the way to get google apikey http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048302/google-maps-not-showing-any-map/13488539#13488539

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you already have the key got the link below and add the fingerprint along with your android project package name

You also need to login to your google account

https://code.google.com/apis/console

[image]

Click on create new key. Add the fingerprint along with your android project package name.

[image]

You can see the api key above

Enable google map api v2 from services tab.

[image]

Then in manifest file under application tag

```
 <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="my key"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Visit the [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console)

Login with your Google acocunt and click the API Access tab. Your API key is listed there.

You will also need to enable Google Maps Android API v2 service for your API key. You can do that on the services tab via the toggle button.

Answer (score 1):

```
serverAddress = new URL("http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q="
                    + Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()) + ","
                    + Double.toString(loc.getLongitude())
                    + "&output=xml&oe=utf8&sensor=true&key="
                    + R.string.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY);
```

Where GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEYS is a string in string.xml containing your maps api key

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and my issue was I used debug certificate not release certificate

if you use this for **release certificate** "not debug certificate":

Enter the following at a terminal or command prompt:

keytool -list -v -keystore your_keystore_name -alias your_alias_name

in your_keystore_name write the path for the file you used for signed api which its extension .jks

take the sha1 which you will get in the output and used it to get the key.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#display_your_apps_certificate_information

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `google map of api v1` which is already `deprecated` as stated [`here`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey?hl=en) so you can't generate new api key if your existing api key is wrong.so kindly **move towards**  [`google map of api v2`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

Comment: as u have edited your question from `map` to `google map` ,my answer has no significance.kindly ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

See http://hmkcode.com/getting-android-google-maps-v2-api-key/.

1. Open https://cloud.google.com/console.
2. Select a project from an upper list (if several), or create new.
3. In left panel click on "API and services".
4. In "Control panel" click on "Maps SDK for Android" or create new.
5. In "Credentials" get an API key or create new.