# How to obtain Browser key

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I am using Google map API v2 in android and places API and for loading places. 
I need browser key and Google map API key. i generated Google map API  key and used it map load successfully but when i did not understand how to generate browser key.please help me thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In https://code.google.com/apis/console -> API Access part in left panel ->

[image]

And in new panel:

[image]

And for get API Key for your application:

[How to get google map apikey in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462140/how-to-get-google-map-apikey-in-android)

Comment: i will accept your answer if you show in both new and old console and with the requirement to get Key...

Comment: there should be another step after create new key which look alike the pic above and link answer about Map Api key not browser key. I will accept this answer, link correct one and try to add much detail step as possible.