# how to get places api in android application

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am facing a problem with signed apk. My app contains Google map and places API. I am using released version android key for map and its working fine.But no idea about browser key. I mean I don't know how to get it. Do I need to have browser key in released version as well.

Comment: Check out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124726/how-to-obtain-browser-key

Answer (score 0):

You can get the browser key from your project api console..
Go to APIs & AUTH > credentials