# I upload a apps in google play ,its google map not work but when i run it lacal system to active device it work?

Tags: android, google-maps

I publish application in google play, when download application from google play and install application , google maps not working  but when i connect to

active device to my computer it work.

Answer (score 0):

it's because your Map Api key.
your debug Map Api key is different from Release key.

check this answer to get a Map Api key:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16462351/2943501

then change your key and release app.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using the debug SHA1 key hash on the [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/start).

Change it to the production key hash.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your Google API key is generated using the release key store.It works in debug mode since you make Google API key using the debug keystore